# Calculate modulus for large numbers

Tags: c++, c, modulus

Hi I need to calculate `(2^n + (-1)^n) % 10000007`
where `1 < n < 10^9`

How should I go about writing a program for it in c++?

I know this mod property
(a + b)%n = (a%n + b%n)%n but this wont help me.

Comment: Here's another property: (a*b)%n = ((a%n)*(b%n))%n. Can you prove it?

Comment: `(-1)^n` is just +/- 1 depending on whether `n` is even, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Given

> (a + b)%m = (a%m + b%m)%m

Then, replace both a and b with the same power of 2, and you get the recurrence:

> 2<sup>k+1</sup>%m = (2<sup>k</sup>%m + 2<sup>k</sup>%m)%m

You probably already figured your formula allows you to break down your problem into:

> (2<sup>n</sup> + (-1)<sup>n</sup>)%P = (2<sup>n</sup>%P + (-1)<sup>n</sup>%P)%P

Then, note that (-1)<sup>k</sup> is either 1 or -1, and you should be able to calculate your problem in *O*(n) time.